# What industry job am I qualified for with a PhD in virology?

Tags: immunology, virology

I'm considering applying for a PhD studying innate resistance to HCV. I enjoy research but I would prefer to have a stable job, instead of moving from contract to contract and writing grants to ensure that I get more funding.

Would such a PhD enable me to transition into industry? What roles would I be eligible for?

Comment: I am not sure if your question should be in Biology S.E. I feel Academia S.E. might be a better place. In addition, it seems you have a preconceived idea of what work in Academia/Industry looks like. I found myself in the exact same situation once and went for the industry. All I would say is that this old adage of job security and higher wages in the industry DOES NOT necessarily hold up in the Life Science industry. My recommendation: Do what you feel passionate about (research/money whatever you want), research companies in-depth (e.g. Glassdoor, salary surveys) before applying.